# Mysql Join tables with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I would like to list post and comments of a given user but also list the post where the given user did not comment yet.

Let's say I have the following tables & contents

Table Post

```
ID  TITLE
1   My post A
2   My post B
3   My post C
```

Table Comment

```
ID  COMMENT         POST_ID     USER_ID
1   My comment X        1          1
2   My comment Y        2          1
3   My comment Z        1          2
```

I run

```
select * from post 
left join comment on post.id = comment.post_id
where comment.user_id=1
```

and of course I got

```
ID  TITLE        ID    COMMENT          POST_ID    USER_ID
1   My post A     1    My comment X      1          1
2   My post B     2    My comment Y      2          1
```

I would like to get all posts event the one not commented by user 1  but I don’t want the comment of user 2

```
ID  TITLE        ID    COMMENT          POST_ID    USER_ID
1   My post A     1    My comment X      1          1
2   My post B     2    My comment Y      2          1
3   My post C
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your condition from where to on clause so you will get the posts even if user has not commented yet

```
select * from post 
left join comment
on post.id = comment.post_id
AND comment.user_id=1
```

### [**See Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4a55/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very fast response !

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select post.`ID`,`TITLE`,ifnull(`COMMENT`,0) comment,ifnull(`POST_ID`,0) `POST_ID`,
       ifnull(`USER_ID`,0) `USER_ID` 
from post 
left join comment
on post.id = comment.post_id
AND comment.user_id=1
```